# How to cast IQueryable<T> to DbSet<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
public DbSet<Item> Items 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return dbContext.Item.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x=>x)
    }
}
```

The above code causes a compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to ... DbSet.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

After adding the explicit cast:

```
public DbSet<Item> Items 
{
     get 
     { 
         return (DbSet<Item>)(dbContext.Item.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x))
     }
}
```

a runtime error happens:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type `'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1[Item]'` to type `'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet'1[Item]'

Any ideas?

Comment: The result of a query simply *isn't* a `DbSet<Item>`. why don't you just change your property return type to `IQueryable<Item>`? (And while you're at it, remove the `.Select(x => x)` - it's not doing anything for you.)

Comment: Not being able to cast something into type X is usually a sign that the something is *not* of that type X. Why don’t you believe the runtime when it tells you that it cannot do that?

Comment: OK, thanks for your coments.

Comment: @poke The message the  "an explicit conversion exist," is confusing at best. It naturally leads to the attempt to do an explicit case. Which then fails with a more clear error message.